# ArgumentError in ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, activeadmin

*I installed ActiveAdmin and log in with default admin name and password, while there is an error and hope somebody can help me with it. Thanks !*

**Here is the error:**

```
ArgumentError in ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController#create 
wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
Rails.root: E:/Ruby/challenger2 - Copy

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:2:in `sign_in'
```

**Part of the sessions_helper.rb file:**

```
module SessionsHelper
  def sign_in(user)

    self.current_user = user    
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= user_from_remember_token
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

end
```

Comment: You can format code by indenting them it 4 spaces. It makes questions much easier to read and answer questions.

Comment: You create yourself the session_helper ? Why create it ?

Comment: I guess he learned from [here](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book?version=3.2).

Answer (score 15):

gem Devise, which Active Admin depends on, probably use "sign_in" function - this name has one of members function of your SessionsHelper module. 
this cause invoke of wrong function.
one solution is not to use activeadmin as an admin tool )))
and the other one is to rename "sign_in" function globally to "sign_in_" for example

and don't forget to restart server: it helps from time to time )

Comment: I went with globally renaming my custom `sign_in` function to `sign_in_` and that got everything working for me. Thanks!

Comment: hmmm... you would oblige me a lot if mark my answer as an answer for your problem )